# What is the best practice for a REST api to manage maximum characters for a field?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api RESTful service that has a few POST endpoints to insert a new object to the database.  We want to limit the maximum characters accepted for the object name to 20.  Should the DB, API, or UI handle this?

Obviously, we could prevent more than 20 characters on any of those layers.  However, if it gets past the UI then the form has been submitted.  At that point, we would want the Service layer or the DB layer to return an informative explanation as to why it was not accepted.  What would be the best practice to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should the DB, API, or UI handle this?

At the very least, your API *must* handle data validation. Everyone has their own opinions on how REST should work, but one good approach would be to return HTTP 400 (Bad Request), with some content that includes information about why the request was bad.

Client-side checking is a definite bonus on top of this. Ideally you'll never even see this code get hit at your API layer. The client should also be capable of handling the potential "Bad Request" response in a graceful way. If there's ever a mismatch between the rules applied by the API and the client, you'll want the client to recognize that its action didn't succeed, and display an appropriate error to help the user respond to the issue.

Database-level checks are also a good idea if you ever allow data to bypass your API layer, through bulk imports or something. If not, the database might just be one more place you'll have to remember to change if you ever change your validation requirements.

Comment: Gotcha so a simple validation that the string does not exceed 20 characters should be valid?  Just instantly return a bad request response to the UI in case it ever makes it through?  That is what I was leaning towards, but I didn't want to add redundant code if there was no point in the service handling it.

Comment: @LeythG: Right. Remember that you have no control over anything outside of your API, so a malicious user could try to deliver a massive payload just to mess with you. Or someone may write a different client against your API some day (for mobile apps, e.g.), and forget to include this check. Or there may be a defect introduced when you upgrade a client-side library that suddenly makes your client fail to do the validation it's supposed to do. The API layer is the single most important point for you to control this.

Comment: That makes great sense, thank you very much for your response and assistance.